# How to create form in samsung smart tv

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

Am very new to samsung smart tv ,here i have to create simple form to do factorial program how can i achieve this?please help me for this silly question and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a form you can usr standard HTML.
See full spec here: http://developer.samsung.com/devices/tv-specs
What content in your form anyway?

Comment: When did Samsung TVs start running Android?

Comment: My bad, got the wrong brand. Samsung uses Linux 2.6. Thank you for the correction. They are kind of similar anyway :)

Comment: thanks for your reply . In samsung smart tv SDK 4.5 i saw scene1.scene,toolbars are there in scene page, shall i  use that one to design my form

Comment: yes that is by default, you can right click on scene1.scene and choose "New" --> and you should see a popup with the option to choose as Samsung Smart TV Apps Kit that's where you start for visual

Comment: can u please send me any program link by using scene i understood what u said but codings? where i hve to write

Comment: and also how to handle events while pressing button on scene.if i run samsung SDK 4.5. emulator means it considers index.html then what about scene1.js and scene.css

Comment: check the sansung developer forum http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/d04/getting_started/create_visualkit_file.html you can get yourself started here